# How do I update the fork when the remote repo changes?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I forked and then cloned a repo (say xyz).

Then xyz got updated and I don't have the updates in my fork.

To get them I tried the following:

```
 git remote add upstream xyz(ssh).
```

Then, git fetch upstream. Until this everything seemed fine. Now when I run -

```
git checkout master
```

I get the error:

```
pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I tried -

```
git update-ref HEAD master and got fatal: master: not a valid SHA1.
```

Again,

```
 git checkout xyz also gives error:error: pathspec xyz.git' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So, how do I keep my fork synced with remote repo and also update the local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `git pull` from the source repository:

```
cd path/to/my/fork
git pull https://github.com/user/source-repository master
```

That will pull and merge the changes from the source repository into your fork.

Replace `master` with the source branch you want to pull from. Also, you can use any type of repository url. In the example I used https.

---

From your question and comments I understand you have a remote named `upstream` and a branch named `develop`. So to merge `upstream develop` into your fork, do:

```
git merge upstream develop
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not help. It jsut says already upto date but its not!

Comment: @Smitha Can you please give me your fork repository url so I can take a look.

Comment: Sorry, that's confidential and private.

Comment: It says this: * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

Comment: @Smitha That's simply means you're up to date. Double check if the branches are correct.

Comment: nope, on my fork, it clearly says- This branch is 103 commits behind xyz:develop. this xyz is also a forked repo from another. I need updates only from xyz

Comment: @Smitha Ok, so you have a remote `upstream` that has a branch `develop`–try the following: `git merge upstream develop`.